# How to filter the tasks that have a non-estimated duration?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I would like to filter only the tasks that have a duration fixed and know.

I have a lot of tasks with an estimated duration, I want to filter the others.

Is this possible under MS Project 2013 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you only want to show non-estimated tasks:-

Create a new filter and filter on the "Estimated" field, where it has a value of "No".

If you require the opposite, and want to *hide* non-estimated tasks there is a pre-built filter called "Estimated" that causes only estimated tasks to be displayed.